# Icon size changed when using BitmapDecoder.Create in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage

We have a method to Convert icon to given size, which likes below:

```
private BitmapFrame GetSizedSource(Icon icon, int size)
{
    var stream = IconToStream(icon);
    var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
    var frame = decoder.Frames.SingleOrDefault(_ => Math.Abs(_.Width - size) < double.Epsilon);

    return frame;
}

private Stream IconToStream(Icon icon)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        icon.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

As we pass the icon, which `height/width` is 32, and parameter `size` is 32.

Actually, the `decoder.Frame[0]` width/height is **1.0**, I don't know why?

Did I miss something?

Comment: `Width` and `Height` are in device independent units. Did you try `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight`?

Comment: @dkozl yes, they both are `1`

Comment: Did you try removing `using ( ....)`? You seem to create the stream return reference to it and then dispose its resources

Comment: indeed it is a problem with disposed stream. If you return frame before disposal, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `IconToStream` which creates `MemoryStream`, copies icon into it, returns reference and then disposes all resources allocated by `MemoryStream` which effectively makes your stream and therefore `Frame` empty. If you would change `GetSizedSource` to something like below that returns `BitmapFrame` before desposing `MemoryStream` is should work:

```
private BitmapFrame GetSizedSource(Icon icon, int size)
{
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      icon.Save(stream);
      stream.Position = 0;
      return BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand)
                .Frames
                .SingleOrDefault(_ => Math.Abs(_.Width - size) < double.Epsilon);
   }
}
```